# Programmatically get a view's dimension that's been set to wrap_content in the xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout

For a dropdown animation, I need to get the actual dp height of a view that has been set to *wrap_content*, thus depending on the number and sizes of its contained views. 
The code sample shows the LinearLayout that I need to know the height of, inside a relative layout with a height of 0. The animation is supposed to increase the RelativeLayout's height to the height value of the inner LinearLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_device_wrpr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/zero_size"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/new_device_dd_button_knob"
            android:layout_below="@id/new_device_dd_button_knob" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/new_device_spawn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

An implementation like the following only returns 0:

```
LinearLayout lL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.new_device_knob_spawn);
            lL.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Christian stated you need to wait for layout to occur before you can retrieve the size of the view. If you're attempting to do this in `onCreate` I would recommend using a global layout listener to execute a callback once layout is complete.

```
final LinearLayout lL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.new_device_knob_spawn);
lL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int h = lL.getHeight();
        // Do whatever you want with h
        // Remove the listener so it is not called repeatedly
        ViewHelper.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(lL, this);
    }
});
```

In order not to use a deprecated method I have this static helper method to remove global layout listeners. This is due to a renamed method in Jellybean.

```
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        removeLayoutListenerJB(v, victim);
    } else removeLayoutListener(v, victim);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void removeLayoutListenerJB(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim) {
    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(victim);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private static void removeLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim) {
    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(victim);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getWidth()` or `getHeight()` will work , but it depends "WHEN" you call it!

It always return 0 if you're calling it in "onCreate" event (that's because the view was not measured yet).